# Placing a div only after clicked object

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Buildgames returns rows:

```
<a>....</a>
<a>....</a>
```

When I click on each `a` the `Buildcar_s` function returns all the data inside an alert.

Instead of this alert I want to put all the results in a `div` under each `a`, so it would look like:

```
<a>.....clicked ...</a>
<div>....
    ...
</div>
<a>....not clicked...</a>
<a>....not clicked...</a>
<a>....not clicked...</a>
```

How can we put a `div` only under the `a` which was clicked?

```
function Buildcar_s(items) {
    var div = $('<div/>');
    $.each(items, function() {
        var car_ = this.car_;
        $('<a>' + this.car_ + '----' + this.Names + '---' + '</a>').click(function() {
            _Services.invoke({
                method: 'GetgamesRows',
                data: {
                    car_Number: car_
                },
                success: function(car_s) {
                    
var div = Buildgames(car_s);
                         $(div).insertAfter($a);
                }
            });
        }).appendTo(div);
        $('<br/>').appendTo(div);
    });

    $("#leftRows").append(div);
}

function Buildgames(items) {
    var place = '<div>';
    $.each(items, function() {
        place += 'mmmmmm<br/>';
    });
    place += '</div>';
```

return place;
}

Comment: Please take more time on the formatting of your question next time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, relevant changes have been commented:

```
function Buildcar_s(items) {
    var div = $('<div/>');
    $.each(items, function() {
        var car_ = this.car_;
        $('<a>' + this.car_ + '----' + this.Names + '---' + '</a>').click(function() {
            var $a = this;
            _Services.invoke({
                method: 'GetgamesRows',
                data: {
                    car_Number: car_
                },
                success: function(car_s) {
                    var div = Buildgames(car_s);
                    // this inserts the HTML generated from the function, 
                    // under the A element which was clicked on.
                    $(div).insertAfter($a); 
                }
            });
        }).appendTo(div);
        $('<br/>').appendTo(div);
    });

    $("#leftRows").append(div);
}

function Buildgames(items) {
    var place = '<div>';
    $.each(items, function() {
        place += '<div style="float: right;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + this.CITY + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + '</div><BR />' + +'<br/><br/>';
    });
    place += '</div>';

    return place; // returns the string created, as opposed to alerting it.
}
```

Comment: i changed the 2 changes you did, but it not work now at all...when i change the return to the alert it will alert the data. do you know where might be the prob?

Comment: I have an idea but i am not sure how to pull it out $('<div id=' +items+ '>' suppose i will give id to each div how i will appent to specific id